# Can MySQL insert empty rows when grouping by minute?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data that deals with what time people arrived at events. The data looks something like this:

```
| entry_id | entry_time          |
  1          2016-03-03 22:26:19
  2          2016-03-03 22:26:23
  3          2016-03-03 22:26:29
  4          2016-03-03 22:40:17
```

I would like to use this data to produce a chart referencing how many people arrived in a given minute. The SQL I've written looks like this:

```
SELECT date_format(entry_time,'%h:%i %p') as time_name, count(entry_time) as time_count
FROM ENTRY 
GROUP BY minute(entry_time);
```

The issue is, the data produced does not contain empty rows for minutes where no entries occur. Is it possible to create them using only MySQL? I have seen examples using days or hours that involve creating a table of all possible information (such as all 7 days of the week or all 24 hours in a day), but it seems for this solution to work I would need to make a table with every possible minute/hour combination– is that correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any insight you may have.

Comment: Use a calendar table (i.e. a table with an entry for every time period) and a left join

Comment: You could just generate two tables on the fly, one with the numbers 0-59 and another with 1-24, then just `CROSS JOIN` the two. If you're spanning more than one day then you could create the couple of rows that you need there.

Comment: Yes. It's possible - but it's not generally a great idea.